# How to insert the value of a global Javascript variable into HTML using jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I have a global variable declared in one of my JS files, and it keeps updating. At certain point I want to show the value of that variable to the user. Simply, I want to add it to my HTML code. I have the HTML code shown below:

```
        <div id="finalPage" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="false">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <h1>Result</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="info-wrapper">
                <p>
                    Result: <br>
                    You got
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to display the value of my variable, which is named "result", after the part written "You got". How can I achieve it? Please note that I'm using jQuery and jQuery mobile for my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the HTML to:

```
<p>
    Result: <br>
    You got <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

and use this jQuery:
`$('#result').text(result);`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nRXV/